# How do I get listening activities from the SoundCloud activities API?

Tags: json, api, soundcloud

I'm interested in showing what tracks a user has listened to lately; but that doesn't seem to be available in the activities API:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#activities

Am I missing something? Is there another API endpoint that gets "listens"?

Comment: Hmm. I thought people from SoundCloud did their dev rel here. No?